# How to do OTA via http, using ESP32 as AP instead of as STA, and using ESP-IDF?

Tags: http, esp32, ota, esp-idf

I need to write a program, using ESP-IDF, which is able to update the firmware of an ESP32-S3-based device wirelessly, without having on-field access to Internet.

I googled and found the example project about OTA:

- OTA: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tr ... system/ota

But this project seems to use the ESP32 as an HTTP client, connecting to a server running on a computer, and both the ESP32 and the computer being connected to the same local network created by a router acting as AP. For the firmware update on-field, I won't have access to Internet or a local network via a router, hence I will need to set up a direct connection between the ESP32 and my computer. I thought that I could do this by using the ESP32 as AP and then connect with my PC to the ESP32-created network.

For using ESP32 as AP, I found the following example project:

- WiFI as AP: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tr ... ted/softAP

and for using ESP32 as HTTP server I found the following example project:

- HTTP server: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tr ... ver/simple

My idea was to try to combine code from the above 3 example projects in order to use the ESP32 as AP instead of as STA, run an HTTP server on ESP32, use a computer as HTTP client to connect to the ESP32 server, and from the computer browser to upload the new firmware file to the ESP32 server, and then copy the new firmware from a buffer to the ota flash partition.

As I don't have experience with OTA at all and less experience with ESP32, I wanted to first ask if the above idea is possible at all or there exists a simpler way to accomplish the OTA. If there is no simpler method, how can I use the OTA code with ESP32 being an HTTP server instead of HTTP client (as the OTA example seems to be coupled to an HTTP client) ?

P.S. Using the ESP32 as HTTP client seems not applicable to me because I will need to know in advance a certain permanent IP address for the computer acting as an HTTP server which I think I cannot have, but I am not sure if I am thinking correctly ?

Comment: I recommend [ESP32 Over-the-Air Updates in SoftAP mode](https://github.com/Jeija/esp32-softap-ota)

Comment: @Bosz Thanks for your hint, it helped me do the task :-)

Answer (score -1):

To update firmware Over-the-Air (OTA) using HTTP and the ESP32 as an Access Point (AP) with ESP-IDF, follow these steps:

1. Set up the ESP32 as an AP: Use the esp_wifi_set_mode function to configure the ESP32 as an AP.
2. Start an HTTP server on the ESP32: Create an HTTP server that can handle file uploads. ESP-IDF has examples that demonstrate creating an HTTP server.
3. Connect to the ESP32 network from your PC: Use a PC as an HTTP client and connect to the ESP32 server.
4. Upload the firmware: Access the ESP32's HTTP server using a web browser or a tool like curl to upload the new firmware file.

To set up the ESP32 as an AP, the code snippet includes initializing NVS and setting the Wi-Fi mode and properties of the AP.

For the complete OTA process, you can refer to example projects such as the OTA and SoftAP examples provided by ESP-IDF. Combining these examples will give you a good starting point for implementing OTA updates in AP mode.

It's important to ensure that the uploaded firmware contains OTA functionality to enable future OTA updates. Use digital signatures or checksums to verify the integrity of firmware updates.

Thorough testing should be performed using automated testing tools to detect and address potential issues early in the process.

ESP-IDF documentation and community forums provide detailed guidance if needed.

Comment: Are you aware of our [policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?